# Mysql insert a tilde ~ in a record

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having a little issue trying to change part of a url in mysql to a URL that has a tilde in it.

Current my site has a url of `domain.com/admin/`. But because I needed to use a shared ssl cert, I have to add a tilde with the linux username in front of it, like this `/~crr/admin/`. I am novice at writing sql, and have searched for this, but can't find this problem.

Here is what I am trying and thats when I get a character error.

```
UPDATE menu_items 
SET menu_links = replace(menu_links, "/admin/", "/~crr/admin/");
```

I tried it without the tilde and it works, so I am pretty sure it is the tilde causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with single quotes:

```
UPDATE menu_items 
SET    menu_links = replace(menu_links, '/admin/', '/~crr/admin/');
```

I don't remember ~ being a reserved character in MySQL. If the above doesn't work try escaping the ~ (PHPMyAdmin uses a ~ I guess when showing approximate data counts)

```
UPDATE menu_items 
SET    menu_links = replace(menu_links, '/admin/', '/\~crr/admin/');
```

Comment: What was it? Single-quotes or escaping?

Comment: The first block of code worked, so I did not try the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Does MYSQL accept CHR()? Maybe try "/" & CHR(126) & "crr/admin/"

UPDATE menu_items
   SET    menu_links = replace(menu_links, "/admin/", "/" & CHR(126) & "crr/admin/");